# Get JSON from an HTTP Post to an Algolia server on Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, algolia

Not sure how to correctly put together the headers for a POST query to an Algolia server using Java in Android.

I have all the info about the request headers from recording the network info in Chrome's dev console

I have the query string parameters:

- x-algolia-api-key
- x-algolia-application-id
- x-algolia-agent

and the form data params

- query
- hitsPerPage
- facets

not working Android Code:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
con.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

con.setRequestProperty("query", queryString);
con.setRequestProperty("hitsPerPage", "20");
con.setRequestProperty("facets", "*");


con.setUseCaches(false);
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
```

This keeps returning a 404 error but it's likely not set up right, really new to network connectivity on Android, anything helps!

Comment: What does http error 404 mean?

Comment: We cannot see that you indeed are sending json. Please add that code.

Comment: 'I have the query string parameters:'. If you POST there is no query string.

Comment: You should have the details of the 404 error in the answer, you can also view it in your Algolia Dashboard as it provides access to the logs of your last API call. By the way, there is an API client for Android that packages all of that for you, why are you not using it?

Comment: request headers are not query params.

Comment: and request properties are not query params either.

Answer (score 2):

I personally used the Algolia PHP API client (on [github](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-android)) in order to perform the search queries, which helps me to don't have to worry about the REST spec.
That one makes things easier to integrate to an Android app, but also integrates a retry mechanism that improves the connection reliability between the device and the API in case of network issue.

The same search query looks like that:

```
APIClient client = new APIClient("YourApplicationID", "YourAPIKey");
Index index = client.initIndex("YourIndexName");
index.searchASync(new Query(queryString), this)
    .setFacets("*", this)
    .setNbHitsPerPage(20), this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never do a direct request to Algolia's servers, as you would lose all the [logic and optimizations](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/basics/should-i-use-the-rest-api-or-one-of-your-wrappers/) they put in place in their API Clients.

Using the [Android API Client](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-android), doing a search query is simple:

```
Index index = new APIClient("YourApplicationID", "YourAPIKey")
        .initIndex("YourIndexName");
JSONObject result = index.search(new Query(queryString)
        .setFacets("*").setHitsPerPage(20));
```

But have a look at [InstantSearch Android](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-android), Algolia's library to build search interfaces. It will be easier, faster, and safer to use it than the API Client.